# String in different variables

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to get a string in different variables with the the .scan expression from Ruby on Rails. So the case is that I've got several checkboxes that are combined 1 string, what I do now is to put each 'number' in a array (But how can I now do if statements to show an image for each number in the array)?

```
<%= @bug.browser_ids %> -> --- - '1' - '5' - '8' - '7' - '6' - '')
<%= @bug.browsers_ids.scan(/\d+/)%> -> ["1", "5", "8", "7", "6"]
```

Comment: `scan` is not from Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save images with names my-image-1.png, my-image-2.png etc .. and display them like

```
<% ["1", "5", "8", "7", "6"].each do |i| %>
  <%= image_tag "my-image-#{i}.png" %>
<% end %>
```